# Outlook (Pro Plus 2019 VL) - No SSO / MFA / 2FA / Modern Auth Prompt

Tags: exchange, outlook, windows-10, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

Can anyone help me out with this. I've had no problem doing this for years, however yesterday I installed a fresh copy of windows 10 pro (MS download tool), and installed a fresh latest copy of Office Pro Plus 2019 VL (O365 deployment tool).

When I open outlook and enter ANY office 365 email account, or outlook.com account, it brings back the standard windows credential prompt, rather than the Single Sign On / modern authentication / 2FA / MFA style prompt. This works correctly on other devices (so a client end problem).

Anyone know why this has suddenly started happening, and how to fix this?

- I have tried both the latest version (I think LTSB2018 10357.20081) and the oldest version (LTSB2018 10336.20015)
- I have tried manually creating the profile and selecting O365 / outlook.com

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

This was never resolved. Office 365 edition apps were deployed instead of "Pro Plus 2019". Office 365 edition apps are compatible with Office 365 / Outlook.com 2FA. I still to this day do not know why the traditional (non Click-To-Run C2R) package versions of Office do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your environment a hybrid deployment? If it is, you could refer to this article. [Outlook prompts for password when Modern Authentication is enabled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3126599/outlook-prompts-for-password-when-modern-authentication-is-enabled)

In addition, you could try to delete login credentials in Windows Credentials. For more details: [Why is my Outlook client not showing a 2FA prompt when Office 365 is protected by Duo?](https://help.duo.com/s/article/3814?language=en_US)

Comment: Thanks for your support. This unfortunately did not resolve it.